# Search Web Part disable preview

Tags: 2013, web-part, search, search-results

How can I disable the **preview of the document** on the *mouse-over* in a search result web part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved using CSS:

```
.ms-srch-hover-outerContainer
{
    display:none !important
}
```

Comment: where do you put that css inside the Display Template  (Default Result web page) ?

Comment: you should create a your custom search page and add that CSS

Comment: You mean the "searchresults.aspx"? What about the document previews on the document libraries. I need to disable there also.

Comment: got it by going to: Site Settings| Site Master Page Settings. There just select the "option specify a CSS file to be used by this site and all sites that inherit from it". link your uploaded css file

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a global solution, I don't think one exists. The behavior is controlled by the display template for the result.

The hover behavior on the Display Template is controlled by JavaScript and a hidden div on the Display Template. You can do any number of things to disable this. Edit the display template and remove the onmouseover event handler is probably the easiest way.